# Use transactions with mariadb and node.js

Tags: node.js, transactions, mariadb, mariasql

Is there a better way to use transactions with the [mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql) library than adding `BEGIN` to the start of the query, and finalizing with either a commit or a rollback?

Currently, if I want to wrap a series of queries in a transaction I have to do something like this:

```
const MariaClient = require('mariasql');
let client = new MariaClient();

client.connect({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "user",
    password: "pass",
    db: "some_db",
    multiStatements: true
});

client.query('BEGIN; INSERT INTO some_table VALUES ("a0","b0"), ("a1","b1"), ("a2","b2");', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        client.query('ROLLBACK;');
    }
    client.query('COMMIT;');
});
```

This seems clunky and potentially error prone.  We are using the [generic-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) to manage the mariadb client, so it seems like there could be some unintended consequences handling transactions this way.

Comment: `client.beginTransaction` is not present? If not, use the mysql library instead

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  If `autocommit` is set to 1, then each statement is its own transaction.  No `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` needed.

Plan B:  Suck it up and use *separate* calls to the API for each statement here:

```
BEGIN;
some SQL statement;
some SQL statement;
some SQL statement;
COMMIT;
```

If the API has special calls for `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, use them instead of performing the corresponding SQL; there may be something important hiding in the call.

In both cases you must check for errors at all steps.  Deadlocks can happen when you least expect them.